# Snowflake join on mixed datatypes not returning results

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running into an issue with trying to join with a subquery from the same table where no results are returned.

```
SELECT 
    CA.PARTICIPANT || CA.RECOGNITION_MONTH || CA.RECOGNITION_YEAR,
    CA.PLAN_NAME,
    PL.PLAN_NAME
FROM
    CSBI_DB.CS_SALES_OPS.CS_COMP_ANLTCS CA
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            PARTICIPANT || RECOGNITION_MONTH || RECOGNITION_YEAR AS MATCH_STRING,
            PLAN_NAME 
        FROM 
            CSBI_DB.CS_SALES_OPS.CS_COMP_ANLTCS 
        WHERE 
            PLAN_NAME IS NOT NULL
    ) PL 
ON
    TO_VARCHAR(PL.MATCH_STRING) = TO_VARCHAR(CA.PARTICIPANT || CA.RECOGNITION_MONTH || CA.RECOGNITION_YEAR)
WHERE 
    CA.PLAN_NAME IS NULL
```

I've tried several variations on the above with no results populating for PL.PLAN_NAME. If I join using just the 'PARTICIPANT' (varchar datatype) field then results will populate (albeit not the desired results) and if I join just on the concatenated 'RECOGNITION_MONTH' & 'RECOGNITION_YEAR' (both numeric datatypes) fields but when combining the two I keep getting null results. I've also tried joining w/o casting the numeric fields to varchar but no luck. This seems like it should be straightforward but obviously I'm missing something...anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The columns are nullable and there is no padding of the months field.

Comment: Thanks for responding Lukasz. I corrected my original response...the columns are nullable. I tried your suggestion but no luck.

Comment: I confirmed no leading / trailing white spaces. Sample row:  Robert Basting12020 NULL NULL

Comment: With such sparse data I could not recreate it:

`SELECT 
    CA.PARTICIPANT || CA.RECOGNITION_MONTH || CA.RECOGNITION_YEAR,
    CA.PLAN_NAME,
    PL.PLAN_NAME
FROM      CS_COMP_ANLTCS AS CA
LEFT JOIN CS_COMP_ANLTCS AS PL
  ON (TRIM(CA.PARTICIPANT) || CA.RECOGNITION_MONTH::INT || CA.RECOGNITION_YEAR::INT) = TRIM(PL.MATCH_STRING)
 AND PL.PLAN_NAME IS NOT NULL
WHERE CA.PLAN_NAME IS NULL;`

Comment: Please provide CREATE TABLE DDL and 3 sample rows as INSERT INTO that should match("as-is") but they do not.

Comment: @StephenT , can you try joining on one column at a time and see for which COLUMN it breaks and dose not return result as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of those columns are NULL, which your comment above indicates that they are, then the concatenation will end up as NULL. This means you won't get a match on that join condition, because NULL doesn't = NULL.

To fix, you'll need to COALESCE the NULL-able fields to a non-NULL value, like: `NVL(participant, '') || NVL(recognition_month, '') || NVL(recognition_year, '')`, or whatever the NULL-able fields are.

Answer (score 0):

If you name you first select result, Snowflake will let you use that label in the where clause, thus the SQL can be a little simpler like so:

```
SELECT 
    ca.participant || ca.recognition_month || ca.recognition_year AS ca_match_string,
    ca.plan_name,
    pl.plan_name
FROM
    csbi_db.cs_sales_ops.cs_comp_anltcs AS ca
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            participant || recognition_month || recognition_year AS match_string,
            plan_name 
        FROM 
            csbi_db.cs_sales_ops.cs_comp_anltcs 
        WHERE 
            plan_name IS NOT NULL
    ) AS pl 
ON
    pl.match_string = ca_match_string
WHERE 
    ca.plan_name IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't follow why this should always return zero rows. The same table can have some NULLs for PLAN_NAME and some non-NULLs -- he's not joining on ca.PLAN_NAME = pl.PLAN_NAME that I can see.

Comment: So true, I see I over simplified my mental model, :hattip: